# Load Cell Specifications

Tags: strain-gage

A [load cell](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/loadsensor.pdf) is specifed as follows...

- Capacity  40-50 kg
- Output Sensitivity 1.0±0.1 mv/v
- Input Resistance 1000±20 Ω
- Output Resistance 1000±20 Ω
- Excitation ≤10 Voltage V

I am a bit confused over the definition of Output Sensitivity as it does not have kg in the units...

If the load cell were loaded with a mass of 25kg and the load cell was excited with a voltage of 5v what would I expect on the output?

25 * 1e-3 * 5 volts?

Comment: A link to a datasheet or part number + specifications sheet would have a better chance at getting meaningful answers.

Comment: All the relevant, I believe, bits were given in the original post so I'm not sure why the down votes.  But for completeness the datasheet I have is [DataSheet](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/loadsensor.pdf)

Comment: People answering a question prefer to read info directly from the source, rather than a subset that you may consider sufficient. Hence the downvotes. Please edit your question to incorporate additional content such as your datasheet link, not in comments. Done that for you this time.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I still think that was harsh given ALL the relevant facts were given in the post; especially harsh to a poor newbie like me; if there had been facts missing then I might have deserved it.

Comment: Many here trust nothing but the datasheet, and prefer to decide relevance for themselves. Apologies if that came across too harshly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to have a go at answering my own question...

**The fact I was missing is that load cell output sensitivity is given with respect to load capacity.**

The load cell's Capacity 40-50 kg.  Call it 50kg.  The load cell's rated Output Sensitivity 1.0±0.1 mv/v.

i.e. At 50kg when 10v excitation is applied the output will be 10 x 1e-3 i.e. 10mV

At 25kg and 5v the output will be (25/50) * 5 * 1e-3 = 2.5mV.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation: The capacity is 40 to 50kg.  generally a max is given and one should aim to use the loadcell near the maximum. It is because, if you use this loadcell to weigh say 5kg, then the relative errors will be high, as errors are specified as percentage of rating. If linearity is 0.5%, then it is 0.1% of 50kg, which is 50 gms. This, as percentage of 5kg is 1%.
Sensitivity; the sensitivity is the change in output for 0 to full scale change in load. The value is specified nominally as 1 mV/V. for a particular load sensor, this will be a fixed value. But if you take 100 load cells, the value could be one within the  range of 0.9mV/V to 1.1 mV./V.. so if excitation is 5V, the sensitivity is nominally 5mv for 50kg load, but for a different load sensor it could be 45 or even 55mV.  The sensitivity is stable to much better than 10% .[Note that +/- 0.1mV/v change in 1mV/V is +/- 10%]. It could be as stable as 0.01%, but does vary with temperature. Look for tempco of span.
 The input and output resistances are about 1000 ohms. The variation is over a number of load sensors. For a particular load sensor it is often stable to better than 0.1%.
Excitation: the maximum excitation is 10V. Note that sensitivity in mV is a function of excitation. If excitation changes by 1%, the output obtained at any load also changes by 1%. 
What is missing in the above is a spec on initial unbalance. Often this is a fixed value and may be +/- 3% of full scale value. Thus with 5V excitation, even at no load, one may get an output of +/- 150uV, while it would change by 5mV when load is  50kg. the initial unbalance is also fixed for a particular load sensor. It can be expected to be stable to within 0.1% of full scale. Nevertheless, it is temperature dependent, and one will have a tempco for ZERO as part of specs.